# Why does size for value types matter when returning a value vs a reference?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I've been doing rust for a few weeks, but I was going through the docs and I came across this example explaining borrowing.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut z:String = String::from("Hi there");
    let copy = first_word(&z);
    z.clear();
}

fn first_word(s:&String) -> &str
{
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();
    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate()
    {
        if item == b' '
        {
            return &s[..i]
        }
    }
    &s[..]
}
```

This compiles and runs just fine, however, if I have it without the "&" like so:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut z:String = String::from("Hi there");
    let copy = first_word(&z);
    z.clear();
}

fn first_word(s:&String) -> str
{
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();
    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate()
    {
        if item == b' '
        {
            return s[..i]
        }
    }
    s[..]
}
```

it does not compile, saying that

> The size for values of type 'str' cannot be known at compilation time.

My understanding is that `&str` returns a borrowed reference, while `str` gives ownership. Why does transferring ownership instead of returning a borrowed reference make a difference in terms of knowing the size of a value at compile time?

Comment: If you own something, surely you need to know how much space you need to keep it?

Comment: @HTNW That's a really good way of putting it. 

If all values of dynamic size must be accessed through a reference, why can I return `String` instead of `&String` when String is mutable?

Comment: @SentientPlatypus `String` keeps the data in a separate allocation, it can represent any size of string but the in-place representation is always pointer + length + capacity